# Start / stop OWIN middlewares?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, signalr, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I wonder if it's possible to start/stop single OWIN middlewares based on a condition / event?

Let's say I host both Web API 2 and SignalR on OWIN to e.g. provide information about network devices and inform the client instantly when they go offline / online. During certain scenarious, let's say "maintenance" mode, the Web API 2 shouldn't be available but I still need to inform clients about a certain event. So I need to stop Web API 2 from answering requests (e.g. with "Not available", "See Other",...) but SignalR should still be available.

Is this possible without restarting the whole web app context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can solve this multiple ways. If all you need to do is to send "Not Available" during a certain time window from ASP.NET Web API, you can simply have a message handler in ASP.NET Web API pipeline that wakes up during this time window and short-circuits the execution of all requests and sends a response. If you want only ASP.NET Web API behavior to be different during down time, this is an option to look at.

If you want changes happening to the behavior of multiple frameworks, you can look at having a single overarching OWIN middleware do this in a single place, as suggested by Brock.

In addition, if you want more control, you can also look at `MapWhen` extension, which can be used to conditionally plug in middleware into the pipeline.

```
app.MapWhen(context =>
{
    // check the condition and return true or false
},
trueApp =>
{
    // Run middleware here like this using trueApp
    // trueApp.Run or trueApp.Use
});
```

Comment: Are there any performance implications to dynamically registering middleware within the `MapWhen` action? Typically, you would call something like `app.UseWebApi(config)` in the `Configuration` method inside Owin startup, which will only occur when the host spins up the web application. Calling it inside `MapWhen` would register middleware for every request that meets the given condition.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to code your middleware to nop based upon your custom condition.